# How to get Object count UFT

Tags: automated-testing, web-application, qtp, hp-uft, uiautomation

I am working on a web application automation, My application has a list item which is having 10 items under it. When i expand the list item for the second time It's showing count as 20 ( though it has 10 elements in UI). Same way if i open for the 3rd time it's showing as 30 and so on ......

I tried adding multiple combinations to identify the list item uniquily, But I could not get the actual issue.

Note :::  When I close the UI / Refresh the page I am getting proper count.

Comment: Question is not clear. Please elaborate more

Comment: Added few more details for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear from your question, but it sounds like you don't track which objects you've already counted, so when the popup is reopened, you're counting the previously selected list elements for the second time.